# Why does a torch gradient increase linearly every time the function is backpropagated?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch

I am trying to understand how PyTorch backpropagation works, using the following code.

```
import torch
import numpy
x = torch.tensor(numpy.e, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.log(x)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

The result is `tensor(0.3679)`, as expected, which is `1 / x`, which is the derivative of `log(x)` w.r.t. `x` with `x = numpy.e`. However, if I run the last 3 lines again WITHOUT re-assigning `x`, i.e. do

```
y = torch.log(x)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

then I will get `tensor(0.7358)`, which is twice the previous result. 
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradients are accumulated until cleared. From [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward) (emphasis mine):

> This function accumulates gradients in the leaves - **you might need to zero them before calling it.**

This zeroing can be done by way of `x.grad.zero_()` or, in the case of a `torch.optim.Optimizer`, `optim.zero_grad()`.

Comment: Just to add this has practical relevance due to linearity of differentiation. Since applying backward to a + b is the same as applying backward to a then b.